# XSLT apply a template with a condition in the path

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm quite new to XSLT so I'm trying to apply a specific template (header-component) and then load all of them except the header-template.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="page-components/header-component"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="page-components/*"/>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

With my solution the header-component is being loaded twice (as obvious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="page-components/*"/>
```

just write

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="page-components/*[not(name()='header-component')]"/>
```

to exclude the element you already processed.

Comment: your solution worked. Can you recommend me some online info where I can learn XSLT properly?

Comment: I think i learned it through trial and error. Try to build something, run into issues, google about them or ask here. I remember reading w3schools.com a lot.

Comment: @TiagoNeto - If you scroll to the bottom of the [XSLT tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info), there are some online resources listed. I haven't used any of them, but they were done by Dimitre Novatchev so I'm very comfortable recommending them anyway.